# Hibernate with JSP problems

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, sorting

I've got 2 entities with `OneToMany` relation. Also I have one jsp where I'm getting some related values using DAO which returns me list with one key.

***For example:***

**University**

*Student a, Student b.*

I don't need to write another method in DAO to get related Students. Just one method in University and I can get all values from Students, because `OneToMany` relation. It's ok. But I want to sort Student by something. And this is the trouble. University entity haven't got Students columns.
How can I fix this? Can I sort my table(Student) in mysql and get it from DB already sorted?
This is my jsp:

```
<c:forEach items="${spyList}" var="spy">
        <c:forEach items="${spy.spyPath}" var="spyPath">
            <table style="width: 800px; border-collapse: collapse;" width=""
                align="">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>

                        <td
                            style="width: 450px; letter-spacing: 0px; word-spacing: 0px; vertical-align: top;"><strong>

                                <strong> <a
                                    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}${spyPath.url}">${spyPath.title}</a>
                            </strong>
                        </strong><br></td>
                        <td style="width: 20px; letter-spacing: 0px; word-spacing: 0px;"><br></td>
                        <td
                            style="vertical-align: top; letter-spacing: 0px; word-spacing: 0px;"><div
                                id='date'>
                                <small>${spyPath.time}</small>
                            </div> <br></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>
```

This is my Spy:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "spy")
    private List<SpyPath> spyPath = new ArrayList<SpyPath>();

    public List<SpyPath> getSpyPath() {
        return this.spyPath;
    }

    public void setSpyPath(List<SpyPath> spyPath) {
        this.spyPath = spyPath;
    }
```

And SpyPath:

```
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID")
    private Spy spy;

    public Spy getSpy() {
        return this.spy;
    }

    public void setSpy(Spy spy) {
        this.spy = spy;
    }
```

Comment: I would use datatables for JSP/HTML table sorting on the client side. http://datatables.net/

Comment: Are you asking how to sort a `List<Student>`? Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

Comment: No. I haven't got List<Student>. I have List<Unversity> with one key. I can't sort because it has no reason. How can I sort one value?

Comment: You said: "But I want to sort Student by something. And this is the trouble.". So what is the actual trouble if the trouble is not to sort a list of students? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I haven't got list of students. That's why.

Comment: You said the company has a OneToMany association with Students. Show us the code of those two entities. If what you said is true, the Company should have a collection of students.

Comment: `public List<SpyPath> getSpyPath()`: this returns the list that you want to sort and display, doesn't it? So, sort it before displaying it in the JSP. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

Comment: Hm. Thanx. You could post your answer and I will choose it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public List<SpyPath> getSpyPath()
```

this returns the list that you want to sort and display. So, sort it using a comparator before displaying it in the JSP.

The Java tutorial has [a whole chapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) explaining how to sort collections.

Comment: `Bound mismatch: The generic method sort(List<T>) of type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List<SpyPath>). The inferred type SpyPath is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<? super T>>`

Comment: `Collections.sort(spyPath, new SpyPath());`

Comment: You need a Comparator. Read the link I sent you twice already.